# Spring profiles not taken into account when using XML schema-based configuration

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms, spring-bean

I want to initialize an ActiveMQ broker using spring beans when the `integration` spring profile is NOT active. I want to start the broker only in default profile. The setup would be like this:

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">
....
<beans profile="!integration">
    <!-- ** Standalone ActiveMQ server ** -->
    <amq:broker useJmx="false" persistent="false">
        <amq:transportConnectors>
            <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
        </amq:transportConnectors>
    </amq:broker>
</beans>
</beans>
```

Spring seems to ignore the `<beans>` tag completely, even if the profile is default. Even removing the `profile=!integration` attribute doesn't fix the pb.

It works perfectly well however if I move the broker initializing bean it outside of the beans tag, like this:

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">
<!-- ** Standalone ActiveMQ server ** -->
    <amq:broker useJmx="false" persistent="false">
        <amq:transportConnectors>
            <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
        </amq:transportConnectors>
    </amq:broker>
</beans>
```

However this loses beans profiling. What could I be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that `amq:broker` is not initialized no matter what. The work-around I found was to wrap the amq:broker in custom bean like this :

```
 <beans profile="!integration">
  <bean id="embeddedJmsServerWrapper" class="eterra.ca.xinterface.common.EmbeddedActiveMQServer">
        <property name="server">
            <amq:broker useJmx="false" persistent="false">
                <amq:transportConnectors>
                    <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
                </amq:transportConnectors>
            </amq:broker>
        </property>
    </bean>
</bean>
```